# Integrate $\frac{1}{x \cdot \sqrt{x^2 + 1}}$ without trigonometric substitutions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, substitution

For my current ODE class I need to solve the integral

$$\int\limits_1^z \frac{1}{u \cdot \sqrt{u^2 + 1}} \,du$$

Every solution I've seen uses trigonometric substitution (using $x = \tan(t)$), but I don't know all the integration rules (besides $\sin$ and $\cos$) by heart. Therefore I wanted to ask, whether it is possible to solve this integral without the use of trigonometric substitution?

The indefinite solution

$$\ln(u) - \ln(\sqrt{u^2 + 1} + 1)$$

doesn't exactly scream for trigonometric functions.

Comment: It screams for an hyperbolic function.

Comment: If you're willing to use inverse hyperbolic functions, then
$$\frac{d}{du}\left(-\text{csch}^{-1}u\right)=\frac{1}{u\sqrt{1+u^2}} $$
for $u>0$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not comfortable with hyperbolic functions as well.. Maybe I should really take a few hours to get to know trigonometric / hyperbolic functions a bit more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\int_1^z \frac{1}{u \cdot \sqrt{u^2 + 1}} \,du=\int_1^z \frac{u}{u^2 \cdot \sqrt{u^2 + 1}} \,du$$

Set $v= \sqrt{u^2+1} , dv =\frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2+1}}du$.

$$\int_1^z \frac{u}{u^2 \cdot \sqrt{u^2 + 1}} =\int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{z^2+1}} \frac{dv}{v^2-1} \,du$$

Comment: I really like this approach. But what exactly is the formal argument here? Since it doesn't use the definition of the formal integration by substitution. I know the argument like this. If a function $f$ is integrable over $[c, d]$ and $\varphi: [a, b] \rightarrow [c, d]$ is differentiable then $(f \circ \varphi) \cdot \varphi'$ is integrable over $[a, b]$ and we have $\int_c^d f(x) \,dx = \int_a^b f(\varphi(x))\cdot \varphi'(x) \,dx$.

Comment: I missed some conditions, such that $\varphi$ is _continuously_ differentiable and should map to the domain of $f$.

Comment: Even if you use questionable methods, when you get an alleged antiderivative you can check it by differentiating.

Comment: @user7802048 Set $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2-1}$ and $\phi(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}$, with the obvious $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: @N.S. Ok, I should've come up with this... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This can be an another hint, that is to take $$x=\tfrac{1}{t}.$$